# what happens if this command is executed (get-vm cmdlet)?

Tags: powershell, variables, error-handling, undefined, powershell-cmdlet

I was curious what will be the result if the $vm_name was undefined

```
get-vm -name $vm_name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I did not find any related questions or documentation on this. What i know is undefined variable value is $null but need to know what will be the output of this command

Note: This command was used in VMWare

Comment: When the variable `$vm_name` is undefined you will get a `ParameterArgumentValidationError`

Comment: Note that both VMWare and Hyper-V have got `Get-VM` cmdlet.

Comment: with reference to vmware?

Answer (score 0):

the output of this command is the VM details of the virtualization server "hyper-v"
as follows:
[image]

reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vm?view=windowsserver2019-ps